# Error when django-polaris installation

Tags: stellar-sdk, anchor, python-sdk

When I try to install django-polaris using the command *pip install django-polaris* it thrown an error

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-polaris (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django-polaris

Looking for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your `pip` installation is for Python 3. If you have `python3.3` or higher installed, you can test with a non-system `pip` by creating a virtual environment.

```
mkdir test 
cd test
python3 -m venv .venv
. .venv/bin/activate
pip install django-polaris --index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
```

If it works, something is wrong with your system `pip` or `pip3` installation. If it doesn't it is either a connection issue or you are using a stale PyPi repository. Use the `--no-cache-dir` to ensure no locale cache is used.